# Access WSL2 localhost services from another local account

Tags: windows, localhost, wsl2

I've created WSL2 services that I can access through localhost in the web browser on the Windows account that runs WSL2. However, I would like to access the services on a kiosk user on windows 11. I've scheduled a task to run the service at boot and it works, but when I try to access it through the kiosk user, it says "localhost connection refused". I've enabled all port in the firewall settings.

Anyone has a clue of what I can do to allow connection?

Comment: Finally got around to trying this, and I'm not able to reproduce.  I have a second user on my system -- Non-administrator, local-account.  When I start `python m http.server 8000` under my normal user in WSL, then switch to the other account, I'm still able to accesss `localhost:8000` from the browser.  Here's a guess -- Does it work for you if you start the process manually, but it fails if the service is started via scheduled task (without logging into the *desktop* with your main user)?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds It's working in non kiosk mode. Edge kiosk is sandboxed. There's a way to enable localhost via Azure if the computer is managed by an enterprised, but I can't find a way to do it locally.